# Can't get to compile comparison of unodered_sets

Tags: c++11, templates, unordered-set

I have a couple of unordered set defined as:

```
std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<const T>, MyHash<T>, MyEqual<T>> const &map1;
std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<const T>, MyHash<T>, MyEqual<T>> const &map2;
```

With the functors defined as:

1. Hash:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyHash
{
    inline size_t operator()(
        std::reference_wrapper<const T> const &obj) const noexcept
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&obj.get());
    }
};
```

2. Equality:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyEqual
{
    inline bool operator()(
        std::reference_wrapper<const T> const &lhs,
        std::reference_wrapper<const T> const &rhs) const
    {
        return (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&lhs.get()) == reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&rhs.get()));
    }
};
```

Basically using the memory address of the referenced object as a hash and checking if two references are equal if they share the same memory address for their underlying object.

This works fine, **EXCEPT** when I try to compare if two sets are identical:

```
if(map1 == map2)
```

It doesn't compile, and instead, returns:

- GCC:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of ‘bool std::__detail::_Equality<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::_M_equal(const __hashtable&) const [with _Key = std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Value = std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = MyEqual<std::basic_string<char> >; _H1 = MyHash<std::basic_string<char> >; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true>; std::__detail::_Equality<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::__hashtable = std::_Hashtable<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> > >, std::__detail::_Identity, MyEqual<std::basic_string<char> >, MyHash<std::basic_string<char> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true> >]’:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unordered_set.h:1671:40:   required from ‘bool std::operator==(const std::unordered_set<_Value1, _Hash1, _Pred1, _Alloc1>&, const std::unordered_set<_Value1, _Hash1, _Pred1, _Alloc1>&) [with _Value1 = std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Hash1 = MyHash<std::basic_string<char> >; _Pred1 = MyEqual<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc1 = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> > >; _Value = int; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
/home/my_test.cpp:526:28:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1957:47: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘const std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char> >’)
    if (__ity == __other.end() || !bool(*__ity == *__itx))
                                        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

- CLang:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1957:47: fatal error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >' and 'const std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >')
          if (__ity == __other.end() || !bool(*__ity == *__itx))
                                              ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/unordered_set.h:1671:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__detail::_Equality<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::__detail::_Identity, MyEqual<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MyHash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, true, true>, true>::_M_equal' requested here
    { return __x._M_h._M_equal(__y._M_h); }
                      ^
/home/my_test.cpp:526:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::operator==<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MyHash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MyEqual<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >' requested here
        if(map1 == map2)
```

I can't figure out why, since I'm already providing a comparator for the equality when defining the set. I can certaily do the comparison explicitly, but since the STL already does that for me, I'd rather avoid writing redundant code.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? They'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but [`unordered_set::operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp) requires that the elements be [*EqualityComparable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable), and uses plain `==` to compare them rather than the set's equality comparator.